# CKEditor : Code Snippet in Ckeditor not working with Laravel 5.3

Tags: ckeditor

**Need to show saved Code Snippet on CKEditor for editing purpose.**

I am using

```
Code Snippet along with Ckeditor at Laravel 5.3
```

Everything is OK. I can add Code and upload code in Database. Code also shown in the Target Page.

When I need to edit post, I get the previously uploaded data from the Database to the `textarea`. Inside the `textarea` Code Snippet does not show. Here's an Example...

I uploaded this code

```
<div class="col-md-5 flex-center mainheadright2">
    <nav class="nav nav-inline">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Get Full Access</a>
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Hire Me</a>
    </nav>
</div>
```

While uploading this `Code` shows properly in the `textarea`. Also shows properly in `Target Page`. But while I get this `Code` again in the `textarea` to edit, it shows the following.

```
Get Full Access Hire Me
```

I want to get code as snippet every time I want to edit post.

What should I do?

Comment: Store it as htmlencoded text, so you can be sure, it wont render automatically.

Comment: @RápliAndrás Thanks so much. You're a life saver